# How can I call a simplekml module object?

Tags: python, simplekml

I'm new to programming and I can't able to run this code it often shows an error like module object is not callable. Can anyone sort this out for me?

```
import simplekml
kml = simplekml.kml() #what's wrong here?
kml.newpoit(name="sample",coords[(11,12)])
kml.save("H:\\python\\point.kml")`

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/programs/practice.py", line 2, in <module>
    kml = simplekml.kml()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask !

Comment: It's `kml = simplekml.Kml()` (notice **capital *K***).

Comment: At the very least edit the title to reflect what problem you have, so that people with similar problem in the future can find it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you meant to call `simplekml.Kml()` (with capital **K**) to create an instance of this class. So probably it was just misspelling.
`simplekml` is a module, which you import in the very first line of your code.
I advise you to have a look at `simplekml.Kml` [class documentation](https://simplekml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kml.html#simplekml.Kml).

Answer (score 0):

`simplekml.kml` is a module inside `simplekml`, and thus isn't callable, as the error message says. You probably meant to call `simplekml.Kml()` (with a capital K), to create a `Kml` instance.